# Can current be drawn from ground in a SWER transmission setup?

Tags: ground, grounding, power-engineering

I am almost certain that this is a ridiculous question, but cannot figure out why it wouldn't work.

From what I understand, current from the electrical station is distributed to houses through power lines, then, to complete the circuit, returns to the station through the earth. Is there anything stopping someone from burying two electrodes of a simple,  low-impedance element deep enough into the ground that the current will travel through it in its path back to the power station?

```
Low impedance bulb

 |---@@@@---|
 |          |
 | gnd      | gnd
_|_        _|_
 _          _
 -          -
```

Comment: AFAIK the earth is never used as a conductor for power, presumably because its resistance would be too high. It is a reference potential, but not used to carry any significant current.

Comment: Not necessarily. Take a look. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_wire_earth_return

Comment: This seems like a perfectly valid EE question about real systems, and one that is specifically about application of engineering theory rather than industrial practice.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen It is normally done in lower income areas where the cost of the conductors is a real problem.

Comment: The real problem with such a scheme is that the ground current is widely dispersed; there's a low current density at any given point. Furthermore, the voltage gradient is very low: the current passing through the primary load produces a voltage drop relative to the total resistance of the ground path, and this drop is spread out along the entire distance from source to load. Adding two electrodes and shorting them with a low-impedance load is simply going to cause the voltage gradient in the ground to redistribute itself without delivering any significant power.

Comment: If you add up all the ground leakage cap current in your house like 2mA per computer PSU's You might be able to power some LED lights. But that's very unreliable, unlikely and not worth cost of the copper pipes. **You can do it now, Measure the voltage drop from Neutral to ground in your power panel without having to add grounding rods**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, power is generally not delivered by using the earth as one of the conductors.  This has been done in the past, but most of those have been replaced, and I don't think anything new is getting installed like that.

You are however right in that two stakes in the ground in line with the current flow at the right location where the ground is being used as a conductor would exhibit a potential.  And, you could extract power from that.  The funny thing is you'd actually be doing the electric utility a favor by making the overall ground resistance a tiny bit lower.  In other words, the power you would extract would be less than the wasted power it would displace.

There have been cases in the past where these ground currents have causes problems.  For example, a pipe coming in one side a house can be at a different potential than the ground at the other side of the house.  Under the right conditions people have gotten zapped.

However, things aren't done this way anymore in part because of the problems but also because the loss was high.  Where the current went in the ground was unpredictable, and sometimes it got concentrated in inconvenient places where the resulting potential offset would cause trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Provided that the resistance of the load and the leads to the taps is comparable to that of the earth path in between this could work.

However that may not be practical to achieve unless the soil resistance is high.  Likely most high-resistance cases are local problems at the terminal points, rather than poor conductivity of the planet itself, so the "tap" might have to be within the local zone of one of the terminals.

Similar situations with more resistive return paths can be demonstrated (or encountered as safety problems) - salt water for example.